# can we get id="CodeTxt" using @RequestParam("custCode")

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

jsp:

```
<form:input mandatory="true" id="CodeTxt" path="custCode" cssClass="txtfield
 controlWidth" readonly="false"jsValidation="checkAlphaNumeric" />
```

Controller class:

`public @ResponseBody JsonResult fetchCustomerList(@ModelAttribute("customer")Customer customer,@RequestParam("custCode") String customerCode`

do we fetch our parameters with name or id if yes then how we are fetching the values from `@RequestParam("custCode")`.Are we mapping our parameter with `path="custCode"`??
did JsonResult has done some thing behind the screen??
this is a code snippet and running properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a form request to a server, form data are available as key / value pairs, where the key is the `name` of the form field (HTML attribute `name="custCode"` is generated for you when you use: `path="custCode"`). `Id` attribute is not relevant in this case and you cannot reference form field by its `id` instead of `name` attribute.

If you need to retrieve value of the `id` you can store it as an additional hidden field value for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custCodeFieldId" value="codeTxt"  />
```

and then retrieve the value of id using additional 
`@RequestParam("custCodeFieldId") String custCodeFieldId`

Comment: so behind the screen it is adding the name attribute like name="custCode" so that we can access it as @RequestParam("custCode")

Comment: yes, you understand it correctly now - btw the best way to see what is generated is to look at the final HTML code using some Page Source View or inspect generated HTML elements using Firebug (Firefox plugin).